# Why is my useEffect run infinitely when dependencies is set to state changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i have a function to get wishlist item from database and save it to the wishlist state, if i want to add or remove the item from wishlist i want to run the useEffect again so i dont need to refresh the page to see the changes. Its working but my useEffect is running infinitely. How do i fix this problem ?? Thanks in advance.

```
const [ wishlist, setWishlist ] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    
    const getWishlist = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await userMethod.get(`/wishlist/user/${user}`);
        if (mounted) {
          setWishlist(response.data[0].products);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
  
    getWishlist();
  
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, [wishlist]);

 const isProductInWishlist = wishlist.some((item) => item.productId._id === product._id);
  
{ user ? 
            <Flex gap="10px">
              { isProductInWishlist ? 
              <Button  width="200px" padding="15px" colorScheme='teal' variant='solid'  cursor="pointer" fontWeight="500" 
                onClick={deleteWishlistItem} leftIcon={<BsHeartFill />}>Remove from Wishlist</Button>
               :
              <Button width="200px" padding="15px" colorScheme='teal' variant='solid'  cursor="pointer" fontWeight="500" 
                onClick={addtoWishlist} leftIcon={<BsHeart />}>Add to Wishlist</Button>
              }

              <Button width="200px" padding="15px" colorScheme='teal' variant='solid'  cursor="pointer" fontWeight="500" 
              onClick={handleClick} leftIcon={<BiCart />}>Add to Cart</Button>
            </Flex>
            :
            null
          }
```

Comment: You are updating the WishList even inside the useEffect. That's why it keeps re-rendering. And on each change, it again call the api and update the value of WishList

Comment: Move your getWishList Function outside the useEffect

Comment: Why is `wishlist` a dependency of this `useEffect`?

Comment: You're not using `wishlist` in the useEffect so remove it as a dependency. If you had to use it there are workarounds but you don't need to. If you have eslint setup with rules of hooks it should tell you about missing or unnecessary deps.

Comment: i want to display the icon heartFill if the product is inside the wishlist state and if it is not exist i want to display the heart without fill. I also have a add product to wishlist and remove product from wishlist function. The idea is if the item is removed / added i want to run the function and change the icon based on if its exist without refreshing the page

Answer (score 3):

By using `useState`, you keep track of the state of the `wishlist`. This means that any updates you make by calling `setWishlist` will trigger a re-render.

`useEffect` takes an array of dependencies that will cause the function passed in it to run every time one of the dependencies changes.

By adding `wishlist` to the `useEffect`'s dependency array, you:

1. Run the code inside `useEffect`
2. This will fetch the array and update `wishlist` which triggers a re-render
3. Since `wishlist` has changed (from an empty array to an array with items), the code inside `useEffect` will run again
4. The array of items for `wishlist` will be fetched again and `setWishlist` will be called again. Even though the array contains the same items, arrays are not considered equal as they point to different memory addresses. This means that your `useEffect` "thinks" that `wishlist` has changed again, so it will run the `useEffect` code again, which will call the state setter (`setWishlist`) which will trigger another re-render and so on.

Since changing the `wishlist` will automatically trigger a re-render you do not need to "force" another one with `useEffect`.

You can just fetch the wishlist items *once* (after the component has mounted), which can be achieved by listing no dependencies for your `useEffect` as such:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    
    const getWishlist = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await userMethod.get(`/wishlist/user/${user}`);
        if (mounted) {
          setWishlist(response.data[0].products);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
  
    getWishlist();
  
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

The code inside `useEffect` will run once, updating `wishlist` by calling the setter which will trigger the re-render and your UI will be updated.

More info can be found [in the React docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-effect-keeps-re-running-in-an-infinite-cycle).